# I am stuck at this point in learning ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am learning ArrayList in Java. I am making a program for Guessing a word. I have copied and pasted some code from tutorial. But i dont know how to use them. Program is compiling successfully. But nothing is in output. **Here is Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//  Below 4 lines are mine. Trying to call methods.
        String[] ospd = { "hi,bye" };
        mustHaveAt('h', 0, loadWords(6, ospd));
        mustNotHave('h', loadWords(6, ospd));
    }

    public static List<String> loadWords(int len, String[] ospd) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(1000);
        for (String word : ospd) {
            if (word.length() == len) {
                words.add(word);
            }
        }
        return words;
    }

    public static void mustHaveAt(char ch, int position, List<String> aList) {
        for (int i = aList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String word = aList.get(i);
            if (position >= word.length() || word.charAt(position) != ch) {
                aList.remove(i);
            }
           if (position < word.length() && word.charAt(position) == ch) {
        System.out.println("Word " + word + " has character " + ch + " at position " + position);
           }
        }
    }

    public static void mustNotHave(char ch, List<String> aList) {
        Iterator<String> itr = aList.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String word = itr.next();
            if (word.indexOf(ch) >= 0) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this code does not prints anything in output, its purpose to demonstrate the logic. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you expect any output?

Comment: How to know word is guessed or not?

Comment: @RazaHaider add output yourself

Comment: can you change ospd to { "hi","bye" }.

Comment: ospd string array length is 1 in your code. then function loadWords in your code return null.  After changing ospd to { "hi","bye" }, loadWords return "hi". To track code flow, you can print result or debug code(I prefer this)

Comment: @whitefang loadWords does not return null. It wouldn't return null even if ospd was empty. However you are right, ospd should be fixed

Comment: (thanks @Steyrix) It should be empty

Comment: ospd can contain many string. I kept only one just to check. Only thing is to change parameter(calling time) in mustHaveAt of int position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if method succeeds (guesses the word) add output yourself.

You can do this:

```
public static void mustHaveAt(char ch, int position, List<String> aList) {
    for (int i = aList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String word = aList.get(i);
        if (position >= word.length() || word.charAt(position) != ch) {
            aList.remove(i);
        }
        if (position < word.length() && word.charAt(position) == ch) {
            System.out.println("Word " + word + " has character " + ch + "at position " + position)
        }
    }
}
```

This code will give you output, if a word with desired letter at desired position of a word will be present